# Use asp.net membership via LDAP

Tags: active-directory, asp.net-membership, ldap, sqlmembershipprovider, adam

We have an intranet system that uses asp.net with the sql membership provider.  We have about 400 users setup in the intranet.  These can include employees, contractors, etc.

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to expose our existing asp.net sql membership database so it can be used by other systems via LDAP.  For example, we have 2 multi-function copy machines that are used heavily for scanning to email.  Currently we manually maintain the email address book saved on the copiers, but we'd like to configure the copier to use LDAP and pull the names and email addresses automatically from the intranet membership database.

Can the asp.net membership be exposed to be used via LDAP?  The systems would only be consuming the user information (read-only); no need to write changes back to the membership database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I don't think so - usually, you would go the other way around: your ASP.NET membership would use LDAP and the AD accounts since they're already there.

Comment: That would be ideal, but we don't have AD to use in this case.  For the foreseeable future the sql membership database will be the central user database, thus I'm trying to figure out a way to access that info via LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the best way is to install an ADAM (Active-Directory Application Mode) on W2K3 (R2) or an LDS (Lightweigth Directory Server) on W2K8 (R2) if you prefer Microsoft solutions or OpenLDAP, OpenDS for open source solution. And then, synchronize your SQL Database with this 'tiny' LDAP server. And why not replace the SQL membership with an LDAP server, it's a bit more standard for authentication.

Comment: Syncing with a "lightweight" ldap server seems to be the only way to achieve what I want.  Should work for us.